# AngularJS empty Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, scope, apply

I've the following code:

```
    theApp.controller("quizMasterController", function ($scope, $location, $http) {
var teamArray = [];

function getQuizRequests() {
        var URL = '/acceptOrReject/' + lookUpCode();
        console.log(URL);

        $http.get(URL)
            .success(function (data) {
                console.log("data.teamArray= ");
                console.log(data.teamArray);
                for (var i = 0; i < data.teamArray.length; i++) {
                    teamArray[0] = data.teamArray[i];
                    console.log(data.teamArray[i]);
                    console.log("this is the teamarray in the getQuizRequests() success function");
                    console.log(teamArray);
                    makeTeamList();
                    $scope.$apply();
                }


            })
            .error(function (data, status) {
                alert("ERROR data cant be loaded");
                console.log("ERROR data cant be loaded", status, data);
            });


    }
function makeTeamList() {
        console.log("!!!!!!!!!!!! this is the teamarray in the makeTeamList()");
        console.log(teamArray);
    }

    $scope.getTeamList = function () {
        console.log("!!!!!!!!!!!! this is the teamarray in thegetTeamList()");
        console.log(teamArray);
        return teamArray;
    }
```

In the console log is the teamArray in `makeTeamList()` the object as I expect, but in the `$scope.getTeamList` is it an empty Array. Why is the array here empty, and not the same value as in `makeTeamList`??

Comment: There must be error in console as you are having `$scope.$apply();` in `$http` success, `$http` callback function doesn't need to run digest cycle..it does internally

Comment: Also you are assigning the data from each of your loops to teamArray[0] instead of teamArray[i].

Comment: where does `getTeamList` get used? Some of this code doesn't make much sense , there is a lot of manipulation for no gain

Comment: Yeah the getTeamList was for debugging. The console.log in the getTeamList shows an empty array, but the makeTeamList is filled.

The Array is for in an ng-repeat

Comment: again, where is it called?

Comment: When the $http.get is called, the $scope.$apply() has to update the getTeamList. It is an Websocket app, so the $http.get is called by a websocket msg. Everything works fine, but I can't see why the teamArray in getTeamList is empty.

Comment: You need to show where the getTeamList() in your markup is getting called, before someone can point you in right direction. Also, can you try calling your getTeamList() inside makeTeamList() and see what happens ?

Comment: I suspect that this `getTeamList()` is being run before the async `$http` call has returned any data, but it's impossible to know without a more complete example.

Comment: How can I call the getTeamList() after the async $http call? I thought that $scope.$apply called the getTeamList() function..